# Terminal menu bar hidden

Tags: centos-6, linux-terminal

I unchecked the menu bar option in the View of the terminal on CentOS. Now this terminal menu bar is hidden. Is there a way to get it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on the terminal, there is a menu item in the context menu to enable the menu bar. (I am assuming that you are using gnome-terminal)

Comment: Don't forget to up-vote!